# What is the purpose of support package in (e.g. how is it different from util)?

Tags: java, oop

I often see the support package in open source projects for example this one https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/dao/support

How is the support package different from util or common. When I'm working on my own projects how can I decide whether to put a class to util or support package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming and putting classes in package is basically done during the designing of the software. People/Teams generally have their individual method of classification and naming of packages. It is up-to you and your design team to decide in which package you want to keep a class and what is supposed to be the name of the packages.